# Getting real time data in Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, real-time-data

Consider the code below:

```
from tkinter import *

screen = Tk()

e =Entry()
e.pack()


screen.mainloop()
```

Now how to get to display the length of the characters entered in the `e` entry widget in real-time? It doesn't matter if the data is displayed in the GUI or Corresponding terminal

Comment: Bind the widget to key release or use `trace`.

Comment: Thankyou @CoolCloud

Comment: What's the purpose of getting the data? Are you wanting to do validation (eg: limit input to numbers only)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are atleast 3 ways to do this here with one being better than the other:

- Using `trace` from `StringVar`:

```
def func(*args):
    print(len(var.get()))

var = StringVar()

e = Entry(screen,textvariable=var)
e.pack()

var.trace('w',func)
```

Every time the value of `var` is changed, `func` will be called.

- Using `bind` to each key release:

```
def func(*args):
    print(len(e.get()))

e.bind('<KeyRelease>',func)
```

- Using `after(ms,func)` to keep repeating the function:

```
def func():
    print(len(e.get()))
    screen.after(500,func)

func()
```

As you can see, the first method is more efficient as it does not *unnecessarily* prints out values when you select all the items(with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>) and so on. Using `after()` will be the most ridiculous method as it will keep printing the length always as there are no restrictions provided.